# What is the correct way to refer to students in high school and lower?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, definiciones

In English, whether a person is studying in kindergarten or college, they are typically simply referred to as a `student`. Although we can say a phrase like "grade school student" or "college student" to be more specific, this isn't typically required in casual speech.

In other languages, like French, even in casual speech there are different words for students in grade school (`élève`) and university (`étudiant`).

Does the word `estudiante` in Spanish generally refer to a university/college student (like in French), or is it more general, like in English?

If there is a distinction, what are the words or phrases used? Are there any variations between different countries?

Comment: English does have “pupil”.

Answer (score 5):

*Estudiante* and *alumno* are both quite general and can refer to anyone from pre-K to doctoral candidates.  In Spain, you'll have the following (all said as *alumno/a* — preferred term — or *estudiante* followed by the indicated terms,)

- **de infantil** - pre-K to Kindergarten

  - more specifically, *de X años* where X is the age.
- **de primaria** - primary school

  - *primero/segundo/etc de primaria* (1º = 1st grade, 2º = 2nd, etc)
- **de la ESO** - obligatory secondary school

  - *primero/segundo/etc de la ESO* (1º = 7th, 2º = 8th, etc)
- **del bachillerato** - (senior) high school

  - *primero/segundo del bachillerato* (1º = 11th, 2º = 12)
- **universitario**<sup>1</sup> - generic university

  - *licenciando*<sup>1, 2</sup> or *de grado* - undergraduate student
  - *de posgrado* - generic graduate student
  - *del máster* - master's student
  - *doctorando*<sup>1, 3</sup> or *de doctorado* - doctoral student

No doubt there is *substantial* variation between countries, which I'm sure others will fill in for the systems they're familiar with.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> These terms can be used on their own as nouns instead of just as modifiers for *alumno/estudiante*</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup> If you thought this sounds like it should be *licenciante* instead, you're absolutely right!  Unfortunately, whoever came up with the term wasn't the brightest and no one thought to correct him/her.</sub>
<sub><sup>3</sup> If you thought this sounds like it should be *doctorante* instead, you're absolutely right!  Unfortunately, whoever came up with the term probably was the same one who came up with *licenciando*.</sub>

Comment: About your note 2: "licenciante" is whoever licenciates another person, and "licenciando" is the one that is about to get a license. These pairs of words are common in spanish, like "arrendatario" and "arrendador".

Comment: About "de la ESO" could simply be "de secundaria".

Comment: -ando is, as far as I'm aware, only used to make two nouns — the two here. The active participle should be the one used for someone in the process of doing something. Hence, el estudiante (not el estudiando), el presidente (not el presidiendo), etc.  This is because the active participle, like the past one, is used as adjective, facilitating the transition to a noun. The present participle cannot be used as a noun, hence the illogic of any word "el —ando" or "el —iendo".

Comment: "El estudiante" is the one performing the action of studying. It is not the same as "el doctorando", because he is *not* the one performing the action. The University gives him the Doctor degree, so the university performs the action on him. "No es lo mismo estar jodido que estar jodiendo", C.J.Cela dixit.

Comment: Por cierto... También tenemos http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=examinando (el que es examinado), sumando (el que es sumado), sustraendo (el que es restado), desposando (el que está contrayendo matrimonio, osea, siendo desposado), etc.

Comment: How many people say "La universidad me doctoró en algo" versus "Me doctoré en algo"? *Que te joden o que te jodes a ti mismo es lo mismo: estás jodido.* That's probably why *doctorante* has a decent bit of use elsewhere, even if not formally accepted by the RAE.

Comment: How many people say something does not mean it is correct. You can not doctorate yourself. I have never ever heard "doctorante". And in any case the "doctorante" would be the professor making a student a new doctor. Doctorante/Doctorado like cambiante/cambiado.

Comment: *Doctorarse* is perfectly accepted by the RAE.  You haven't heard doctorante because it's not used in Spain.  *Examinante*, for instance, can be both the one who gives an exam, and the one who takes an exam (se DRAE).  A *mutante* is something *que muda*, but often itself.  *Una tortuga mutante* isn't *una tortuga que va mudando a otras cosas*, but rather *una tortuga que va mudándose*.

Usage is changing, I admit I'm old fashioned.  You prefer modern usage.  I'll let you keep your *proyectandos* (que no son nada proyectados, pero que sí proyectan al final de la carrera).

Comment: Who said about *proyectandos*? Please do not put in my mouth words I have not used. The person creating a project is the *proyectista*. On its hand, *mutante* is a bad translation on the english "mutant", in spanish it would have been *mutado/a*. And no, I do not prefer "modern usage". I prefer the one that links into correct spanish/castilian etimology.

Answer (score 5):

Argentina:

1. Educación [preescolar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Educaci%C3%B3n_preescolar#Argentina) (up to 5 years - guardería + "jardín de infantes" = kinderganten). They can be called "**alumnos**", but often simply are referred as "**niños / niñas**".
2. Educación primaria (6-11 years): "**alumnos**"
3. Educación secundaria (12-17 y) : "**estudiantes**" o "**alumnos**"
4. Educación terciaria/univesitaria: "**estudiantes**" o "**alumnos**"

Regarding "alumno" vs "estudiante":  they can be used more or less interchangeably, but "alumno" (pupil) is more used inside the teaching context, for example to oppose it to the  "docente" (teacher). Outside that context, "estudiante" is more used; for example, to tell which is your occupation or role in society.

Answer (score 2):

For Spain:

1. *[Educación] Infantil* (3 years, not mandatory), *[E.] Preescolar* (preschool, 4-5y, not mandatory): They may be referred as *alumnos*, almost never as *estudiantes*. You can use *de Infantil* or *de Preescolar* as specifiers.
2. *[E.] Primaria* (6-11y): They are referred usually as *alumnos*, but also *estudiantes*. Again with a specifier *de Primaria*.
3. *[E.] Secundaria Obligatoria (ESO)* (12-15y): They are interchangeably referred as *alumnos* and *estudiantes*, more commonly the second one. Again with a specifier *de Secundaria* or *de ESO*.
4. *Bachillerato* (academic) or *Formación Profesional* (professional training), (16-17y, not mandatory): again they are interchangeably referred as *alumnos* and *estudiantes*, more commonly the second one. Specifier uses to be *de Bachillerato* or *de Formación Profesional / de FP* but also *de instituto*
5. *Universidad*: This one is subdivided nowadays in

   5.1. *Grado* (*Licenciatura* does not exist anymore): as 4, with its own specifiers *de Grado* and *de Universidad*.

   5.2. *Máster*: as 5.1

   5.3. *Doctorado*: as 5.1, and also *doctorando* without specifier.

Answer (score 0):

I grew up in Costa Rica hearing alumnos and estudiantes interchangeably. In Peru (where my parents are from) they say alumnos for all students. I don't feel like there's a solid rule like there is in French.It varies by country.